# Select all by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select  and deselect all by jquery.  I want to the following structure. When i will click select all then all input will be selected and click for deselect it will remove all section.

Anybody solve this kind of problem?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<ul>
<li>

<label for="ck"><input type="checkbox" name="country" value="ALL"/> SELECT ALL</label>
</li>

<li>

<label for="ck"><input type="checkbox" name="country" value="CD"/> CD</label>
</li>

<li>

<label for="ck"><input type="checkbox" name="country" value="ED"/>ED</label>
</li>

<li>

<label for="ck"><input type="checkbox" name="country" value="DD"/>DD</label>
</li>
<li>

<label for="ck"><input type="checkbox" name="country" value="FD"/>FD</label>
</li>
<li>

<label for="ck"><input type="checkbox" name="country" value="SD"/>SD</label>
</li>
</ul>
<td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Select how? To get the elements in a selector you'd do something like -> `$('input[name="country"]')` ???

Answer (score 8):

#### Simple

```
$("input:checkbox[value=ALL]").change(function() {
    $("input:checkbox[name=" + $(this).prop("name") + "]").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

should work just fine.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H9unt/)

---

#### Advanced

If you want to get a bit more advanced and remove the check on "all" if it's on and they're not all selected, you can do the following:

```
$("input:checkbox[value=ALL]").change(function() {
    $("input:checkbox[name=" + $(this).prop("name") + "]").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
$("input:checkbox[value!=ALL]").change(function() {
    var allCheckboxesAreChecked = true;
    $("input:checkbox[name=" + $(this).prop("name") + "][value!=ALL]").each(function() {
        if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
            allCheckboxesAreChecked = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    $("input:checkbox[name=" + $(this).prop("name") + "][value=ALL]").prop("checked", allCheckboxesAreChecked);
});
```

This will deselect "all" if a subitem has been deselected, and it will select "all" if all subitems have been selected.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H9unt/2/)